# Layer properties dialog in my QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I am developing a plugin which should display some information like geometry of the layer, feature count etc. Now those are currently displayed in QMessageBox.information. I want it to be displayed similar to the QGIS Layer properties Tab.

What changes should be done in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at PyQt4 tutorials on Internet. They should help you understand how PyQt4 applications are structured, and should introduce you to the wide variety of widgets PyQt4 provides you with.

Just to cite some, here is a list of resources you could read:

- [Introduction to PyQt4](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/introduction-pyqt4/)
- [PyQt4 Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/)
- [GUI - PyQt4](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/python/#2)

Once you've done that, you should have a wider perspective on how you can integrate different PyQt4 widgets into your application (i.e., your QGIS plugin) so that you can start customizing its behavior the way you want.

In particular, I recommend you getting familiar with Qt Designer to customize in a graphical manner your dialogs, as well as with the following PyQt4 widgets:

- [QDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html)
- [QLabel](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html)
- [QLineEdit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html)
- [QPushButton](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpushbutton.html)
- [QRadioButton](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qradiobutton.html)
- [QCheckBox](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcheckbox.html)
- [QListView](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistview.html)
- Layouts: [QBoxLayout](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qboxlayout.html), [QGridLayout](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgridlayout.html), [QFormLayout](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qformlayout.html), and [QStackedLayout](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedlayout.html).

There is nothing more we can do for you unless you really spend the time required to get to know PyQt4 applications. If you have specific questions (that a basic Internet search could not resolve) while integrating the widgets you need, do not hesitate to ask.

Note that you have access to all dialogs used by QGIS. Namely, [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/master/src/ui/qgsvectorlayerpropertiesbase.ui) is the base dialog for showing layer properties (you can open it in Qt Designer). However, you should only take it as reference, since it's complex and could easily overwhelm you. Even more, I'm sure you don't want to replicate the QGIS layer property dialog, but to create a simplified one for your needs.

Also note that this is not really a GIS-related question, it could be more appropriate in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).