# Triggering QGIS action when plugin button is clicked?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I tried calling the select free hand tool by below snippet of code.

```
iface.actionSelectFreehand().trigger()
```

I dnt have any idea how to call this when i am pressing a button in GUI. my gui is attached below

[image]

When Select Area from Map is pressed i want the select free hand to be called in my plugin. FYI the name of Select Area from Map in QTDEsigner is areapushbutton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really seem to have read at least one of the resources I collected for you in [Layer properties dialog in my QGIS plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133424/layer-properties-field-tab-in-my-plugin).

If you open, for example [this one](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/), you'll see the answer to your question:

```
button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
```

In your case it would be something like (you might need to edit it to match your plugin structure):

```
self.areapushbutton.clicked.connect( self.iface.actionSelectFreehand().trigger )
```